# Creating a list of locations for files with the same name in different folders

Tags: python, os.walk

I am trying to create a list of paths for multiple files with the same name and format from different folders. I tried doing this with os.walk with the following code:

```
import os

list_raster = []

for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(r"C:\Users\Douglas\Rasters\Testing folder"):
    for file in files:
        if "woody02.tif" in file:
            list_raster.append(files)
            print (list_raster)
```

However, this only gives me two things

1. the file name
2. All file names in each folder

I need the the full location of only the specified 'woody02.txt' in each folder.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full path name is the first item in the tuples in the list returned by `os.walk`, so it is assigned to your `path` variable already.

Change:

```
list_raster.append(files)
```

to:

```
list_raster.append(os.path.join(path, file))
```

Comment: This gives me the location without the file name. It gives me **C:\\Users\\lawtond\\Rasters\\Testing folder\\1** when I want **C:\\Users\\lawtond\\Rasters\\Testing folder\\1\\woody02.txt**

Comment: I thought you don't need the file names because they are the same. Simply use `os.path.join` to get the full path name then. The answer has been updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In the example code you posted you are appending `files` to your list instead of just the current file, in order to get the full path and file name for the current file you would need to change your code to something like this:

```
import os

list_raster = []

for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(r"C:\Users\Douglas\Rasters\Testing folder"):
    for file in files:
        if "woody02.tif" in file:
            # path will hold the current directory path where os.walk
            # is currently looking and file would be the matching
            # woody02.tif
            list_raster.append(os.path.join(path, file))
# wait until all files are found before printing the list
print(list_raster)
```